# How to use FB api with Ionic run android

Tags: javascript, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use FB login with ionic. Currently, it works when I simply use ionic serve because I entered http://localhost:8100/ as a valid Oauth Url.

When I run it on my smartphone, the URI is file:///android_asset/.... which is not a valid address for facebook :(.

What should I do to make it work ?

Thank you !

Comment: By changing NAT settings on your router (Internet box), you can redirect traffic toward your computer's local server. This way, you'll be able to access it from the smartphone by using your IP address as a URL (local IP if you're on the same network, otherwise use the public IP). You can then add it to your list of valid Oauth URLs. Note that with a regular Internet plan, this IP address is likely to change over time.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer, that's a work around, but not a real solution :/

Comment: That's why I posted this in the comments section, not as an answer :)